# Confusion on data returned from controller to Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have an AJAX call in one of my coffee scripts which goes to an method of a controller. AJAX call looks like this:

```
auto = ->
  $.ajax
    url  : '<method_name>'
    type : 'POST'
    data :
      <variable_name>: $('element').val()
    success: (data, status, response) ->
      alert('Pass')
    error: ->
     alert('Fail')
```

My method in controller looks like as:

```
def method
  ...
  ...
  <book> object can be invalid object.
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: {book: {title: title}} }
  end
end
```

Now, this 'book/title'(from controller) should be available in my coffee script through 'data' variable(in coffee script). Right?

My question is that when does it will go in 'error' block(for coffee scripts)? I can see that my 'book' object is NULL(in controller) but it is still coming in 'success' block(in coffee script).. I thought if the json objects are NULL, it would come into the 'error' block.

Comment: you are confusing ajax error with error handling in your server side code. If a 200 status is returned from server , ajax success will fire

Comment: If below my answer solved your problem then please accept the answer otherwise ask your queries in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever ajax fails (for eg. if there's a routing error or any error in controller's method etc) then only it comes to error block. Here your method works fine, without error, no matter `book` is `NULL` or not.
You can check in controller that if book object is NULL, then return some flag and then check that variable in AJAX success.
For example:

```
def method
  ...
  ...
  <book> object can be invalid object.
  if book.nil?
     format.json { render json: {is_data_null: true} }
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {book: {title: title}} }
    end
  end
end
```

And then in AJAX success block, you can check that flag.